# For how many weeks can I group my students?

Tags: combinatorics, numerical-methods

I thought of an interesting question that I don't know how to solve. I imagine there are numeric results out there somewhere, but I don't know if this question has a formal name; if anyone could link me to any resources about this problem or provide hints to move me along, I'd be very appreciative.

---

I have $n$ students in a class that I need to split up each week into groups of size $k$ (I guarantee that $\frac nk$ is an integer). However, my students are shy and introverted, so I never want any two students to be in the same group twice. **For how many weeks $w(n,k)$ can I keep this up?** For example, in the case of $n=6, k=2$, if I name my students $A,B,C,D,E,F$, I can create the following groups:

$$\text{Week 1: } AB, CD, EF$$
$$\text{Week 2: } AC, BE, DF$$
$$\text{Week 3: } AD, BF, CE$$
$$\text{Week 4: } AE, BD, CF$$
$$\text{Week 5: } AF, BC, DE$$

So, the answer for $w(6,2) = 5$.

If we look at a more complicated case ($n=16, k=4$), things become a little cumbersome:

$$\text{Week 1: } ABCD, \ EFGH, \ IJKL, \ MNOP$$
$$\text{Week 2: } AEIM, \ BFJN, \ CGKO, \ DHLP$$

However, now $A$ cannot be in a group with any of $\{B, C, D, E, I, M\}$, $B$ cannot be in a group with any of $\{A, B, C, F, J, N\}, \ldots$

There's obviously an upper bound here. Let's look at student $A$. Each week she is required to get $k-1$ new groupmates. Since there are only $n-1$ students in total, not including $A$, the upper bound on weeks this can last is:

$$w(n,k) \le \lfloor \frac{n-1}{k-1} \rfloor$$

Is there a way to calculate $w(n,k)$? If so, is there a way to generate the groups to avoid collisions? Just from some paper-and-pencil testing, generating group is really difficult, so I wouldn't be surprised if a numerical answer exists without a method of generation.

Comment: Wow. Right after posting this a coworker directed me to the following link: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SocialGolferProblem.html

Comment: This is called the social golfer problem; you can find some threads on this site under that keyword.

Comment: It looks like your bound is actually decent for smallish $n$ and $k$; indeed the Mathworld article shows that $w(20,4) \geq 5$, whereas your bound is $6$.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is in general open. Particular forms of it have been studied:

Where $n=3z, z\in \mathbb{N}$ and $k=3$ you end up with the Kirkman's Schoolgirl Problem. This corresponds to finding solutions to Kirkman's Triple System (a generalization of the Steiner Triple System). I believe this was solved in generality in the mid 60's.

Similarly, the Social Golfer problem has fixed $k=4$, but this is not solved in generality yet. I've also heard the term "Golfer Problem" used to describe the general case as you've described it above.

To numerically generate solutions you could do some kind of constraint programming or combinatorial programming.

Answer (score 0):

Stirling numbers of the second kind, denoted $S(n,k)$, tell you how many way to partition $n$ elements into $k$ sets.

Comment: That doesn't answer the problem at all. First, the subsets all have the same size, which the sets in the Stirling number sets do not. Second, you want no two in common from one candidate set to the next. So the Stirling numbers of the second kind are much larger than the numbers desired by the OP.

Comment: Good point. Steiner systems might be a better way to look at it then.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a special case of Steiner system :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_system